# Web Service vs Messaging for retrieving view data

Tags: web-services, rest, integration, message-queue, messaging

I have a need to get some data from some external applications to be rendered in the web portal.

I can achieve this by creating a simple web service, using REST or SOAP for example, returning the external application's data in a representation by accessing the external application's database.

I can achieve this too by using messaging, with the request-reply pattern.

These are what i harvested so far with the consideration of scalability and availability issues. Please correct me if im wrong.

With RESTful approach :

1. I can imagine that the stateless REST architecture is easily scalable just as the web servers that can be clustered, whose throughput can be controlled (like how many threads to serve, etc), but i think the bottleneck would then be in the database access.
2. If the external application's database is somehow not available, the REST could just return some error status, and the portal webapp could print soothing error messages.

With Messaging approach :

1. I can potentially 'buffer' all the messages in the
   channels, can even have multiple channels if there are lots of
   requests, and in the same time, can control the consumption rate
   that is reasonable for the database processing capacity.
2. Inavailability issues should be gracefully handled with persistent
   channels, but in this case, it's a synchronous access, and have to
   respond within a time limit if the external application's database
   is not available. I dont think it is advantegous for this synchronous need.

Somehow i kinda prefer RESTful approach for this case, since it's really a synchronous access and of course much more simpler to implement.
But im still in doubt.

Please share your thoughts. Thanks !

Comment: Agree ! Try to use REST regardless of its flaws you have mentioned. It gives high scalablity in later stage of development. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickmalik/archive/2005/04/14/408328.aspx

Bit old, but demarcates SOA and MOA. Your case looks like an SOA where you wanted get data and just post on a page. MOA is completely different in terms of problem space.